# How can I put white space at the bottom of my website, so the floating div never overlaps

Tags: css

I found a lot of questions on stack overflow about getting rid of white space, but I can't seem to figure out how to put it in.

I have a bottom navigation on my site that floats with the page, but if the window is small, the bottom part of the page gets covered up. I would like to insert some white space at the bottom, so when the window is smaller than the length of the page you can still read it.

I've tried adding:

```
margin-bottom: 50px;
padding-bottom: 50px;
```

to the div containing the top page content, but it doesn't work.

Is there something I am missing? Here's a demonstration: http://www.writingprompts.net/name-generator/

Comment: Hello Jeremy, I am fairly confident I can help you with this but it would be more helpful if you provided some HTML and CSS to go along with the example page you posted. I can give you about 100 different ways to achieve this, however not all will jive with your layout.

Comment: I think you are trying to make your footer stick the bottom of the page without overlapping your content, check this page http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/ :)

Comment: Is the "Demonstration" page in fact your page? or is it a page that has the desired effect (which is more often the case when looking at external links like this)

Comment: Definitely take the time to learn the crap out of how the various positioning schemes anchor to each other and impact flow. It's obscenely useful and something most people never quite grok in CSS. It's a bit to wrap your head around at first but once you get to that 'aha' point, it sticks. And yes, by Aha, I of course meant that Norwegian band with the best music video like ever. You'll know you're there when you've jumped through a mirror into an animated fantasy-scape being chased by dudes in motorcycle helmets and scary goggles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#left, #right { 
    margin-bottom: 90px; 
}
```

or

```
#top_section > div { 
    margin-bottom: 90px; 
}
```

It doesn't work on #top_section because you use absolutes and therefore the content actually over extends the div itself, but trust me, either of those two css' i gave you WILL work

Comment: Rockstar! It worked perfectly. Thank you so much, I've been banging my head against the desk all day

Comment: NP, it happens to the best of us.  Sometimes it's the simplest thing we over look

Answer (score 2):

Simply add the following rule:

```
#top_section {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 90px;
}
```

This will make `#top_section` be as big as the floating content inside it.

Comment: Thanks for the response Yogu, but it didn't seem to work for me

Comment: Wont's work because the content actually over extends the section due to the section not having a determinate height

Comment: I see, now I've added a *padding-bottom*, it should work now. The problem is that we don't know the exact size of the footer (only *min-height* is specified for it), so if the footer grows, it will overlap with the content again.

Comment: This solved the problem my users were complaining about, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/fSYmu/ This is a simplified example, having no idea what your layout looks like (I am not going to assume the demonstration is yours... unless you revise and tell me it is) i'll show you how *I would do this*

**HTML**

```
<div class="container"> <!-- main page wrapper -->
<div class="content"> <!-- main content wrapper, backgrounds apply here -->
    <div class="inner-content"> <!-- content inner, where your content goes! -->
    content
    </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">footer</div> <!-- footer -->
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
​html,body,.container {
 height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; // I am important so the page knows what 100% height is.
}

.content {
 height: 100%; // see above... i need to cascade down.
 background-color: green;
}
.content-inner {
 padding-bottom: 100px; // offset for the footer.
}
.footer { 
 width: 100%;
 position: absolute; // stick me to the bottom.
 bottom: 0;
 height: 100px;
 background-color: red;   
}
```

enjoy!
    ​

Comment: `"having no idea what your layout looks like"` Did you not read his question where he post link to his [*page*](http://www.writingprompts.net/name-generator/)?

Comment: no he posted a link to a page which was a demonstration. no mention that it was his. I assumed he wanted a bottom bar ***like that page***. So to the downvoter: My answer is not wrong, it is in fact ***ONE*** correct way to do this. and it will be helpful to future readers.

Comment: good argument i suppose, but it really is more helpful (in my opinion) to directly help the user in his/her direct question, rather than present an all encasing solution, that, in the end, may or may not even really answer the question, or worse, it may cause the questionnaire to become more confused. Not trying to start an argument or anything, just saying, that I feel it is better to "directly" answer the question than to simply through a solution in place and hope it helps. FYI, i tried to change my dv but it wont let me, sorry.

Comment: Agreed, however in this situation I did not feel his question was answerable directly (as I didn't take the stand that the demo page was his.) Either way, at least this discussion is here for future readers so they can at least see it.

Comment: I thought on stack that more generalized was the idea. They want a reference compendium for solving "this kind of a problem." Otherwise it would just be a massive pile of duplicates. Although CSS questions more than 5 years old should probably just be auto-ejected for how much CSS has changed and old browsers have died.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use fixed position in CSS to achieve this.

HTML:

```
<div id="top-section">
     Insert content here...
</div>
<div id="bottom-nav">
     <div id="content">
       Bottom content...
     </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#bottom-nav {
  bottom: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

#content {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 960px;
}
```